# Spring Boot: use logback instead of log4j

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback

I'd like to use [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), for its performance and flexibility, with a Spring Boot project. I added the Logback dependencies to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

... and ensured that the logging, within each of the classes in my project, was created like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

When the project starts, the following warning is displayed in the console:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

It seems that Spring is still trying to use `log4j` and not logback. I tried adding `logging.config=classpath:logback.xml` to the Spring `application.properties`, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

### Update

Both @AliDehghani and @chrylis suggested that `log4j` is being referenced by another package in the `pom`. The output from `mvn dependency:tree` confirmed that `hbase-common` was the source:

```
com.woolford:my-project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:1.1.2:compile
|  [... etc ...]
|  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
|  [... etc ...]
|  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.5.1:compile
|  [... etc ...]
|  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
|  |  \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
|  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
|  [... etc ...]
|  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
|  [... etc ...]
\- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:1.1.2:compile
   [... etc ...]
```

I tried excluding `log4j` (and `slf4j`) from `hbase-common` like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The project failed to build:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.woolford:my-project:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1, com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy -> [Help 1]
```

I tried adding these dependencies to `pom.xml`, but that didn't help.

@AliDehghani noted, in his answer below, that Spring Boot uses Logback by default and so adding `logback-core` and `logback-classic` to the `pom.xml` shouldn't be necessary. I'm sure he's 100% correct. However, when I comment out the `logback-core` and `logback-classic` in `pom.xml` I see several warnings, e.g.

```
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
```

Comment: Is some other dependency also pulling in log4j? You might need to exclude it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you already know this, but i wanted to wrap it up and generalize...

---

there are these three logging frameworks:

- `log4j` (ancient)
- `slf4j` (api used everywhere, there are different backends available)
- `logback` (has nice features and configuration, successor of `slf4j`)

you have to manually throw out `log4j` and replace it with the compatibility bridge `log4j-over-slf4j`.

there is a `slf4j` backend called `logback-classic`.

---

### mvn:

```
<dependency>
    <!-- legacy log4j ==> slf4j -->
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- slf4j ==> logback -->
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>...no maintainer...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...old stuff...</artifactId>
    <version>...ancient...</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

### sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    Seq(...),
    Seq(
      "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.21",   // legacy log4j --> slf4j
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.7" // slf4j --> logback
    )
  ).flatten.map(_.excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "log4j", name = "log4j", artifact = "*"),
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.slf4j", name = "slf4j-log4j12", artifact = "*")
  ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot by default using Logback for its logging. There is no need for adding it explicitly:

> By default, If you use the ‘Starter POMs’, Logback will be used for
>   logging. Appropriate Logback routing is also included to ensure that
>   dependent libraries that use Java Util Logging, Commons Logging, Log4J
>   or SLF4J will all work correctly.

You can also, change the log levels through using `logging.level.*=LEVEL` in your `application.properies`.

Comment: Add your complete `pom.xml` to question. Maybe some other dependency also pulling in log4j.

Comment: `org.apache.hbase:hbase-common` -> `log4j:log4j`

Comment: Apparently, `HBase` depends on `log4j`. Exclude log4j dependency from Hbase dependency declaration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101012/discussion-between-ali-dehghani-and-alex-woolford).